# How to add the function 'log out on other computers'?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

For example, I often forget to log out on your site on other people's computers, but do not always have the opportunity to go back and log out. How to make a function that will automatically close all sessions except my current one, from my computer?

Comment: "I often forget to log out on your site". So it depends on mysite.If i provide an API for that, then only you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are multiple ways to look at this. Below is the one which i use

use TMOUT

Add the following lines to your bash startup file such as $HOME/.bash_profile or create a new bash shell script called timout-settings.sh in the /etc/profile.d directory:

```
## append in $HOME/.bash_profile
## 300 seconds == 5 minutes ##
TMOUT=300
readonly TMOUT
export TMOUT
```

OR /etc/profile.d/timout-settings.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
## 300 seconds == 5 minutes ##
TMOUT=300
readonly TMOUT
export TMOUT
```